# How to use the instance of class in another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using babylonjs in my React app. Since this file get bigger and bigger I try to split it into several parts.

**Scene3d.js**

```js
import * as Setup from './Scene3d/setup'
class Scene3d extends Component {
    ...
}
export default Scene3d
```

**setup.js**

```js
import Scene3d from '../Scene3d'
```

Unfortuantely I am not able to use the instance object of Scene3d. Scene3d just returns the component in setup.js. I want to avoid to add "this" to all function to pass the object to the functions.

I appreaciate your help.

Best

Comment: Hi @Marvin, what do you want to do from Scene3d in setup.js ? Method recall or something else ?

Comment: It depends what you want to do exactly. You can make a singleton out of your Scene3d class or if you don't need an actual instance of Scene3d you could work with static functions. You should read about it first and come back to adjust your question if necessary

Comment: I want to use the instance variable "this" in other files than Scene3d.js. The whole instance including all associated variables.